# Cannot update an array in Main from nested loops inside of Main. How can I assign it's value?

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

So, I am writing my program when suddenly, I run into a problem in which my three  arrays print as null, 0 and null.

The program reads values from a file, and assigns them to the three arrays based on the iteration number.

Here is my code:

```
String  mushroom []= new String [10];
int  weight [] = new int [10];
String  cooking[] = new String [10];

FileReader fr = new FileReader ("7J_Mushrooms.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
System.out.println("Mushroom\t\tWeight\t\tCooking\n=======================================================");
String line = "";


while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

    String [] temp = line.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){  
        if(i == 0){
            mushroom[i] = temp[i];
        }
        else if (i == 1){
            weight[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);  
        }
        else{
            cooking[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }               
 }

// This bit just sorts them by weight in ascending order like a parallel array
for (int i = 0; i < weight.length-1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < weight.length-1;j++){
        if (weight[j] > weight[j+1]){

            int temp = weight [j];
            String tempMush = mushroom [j];
            String tempCook = cooking [j];
            weight[j] = weight[j+1];
            mushroom[j] = mushroom[j+1];
            cooking[j] = cooking[j+1];
            weight[j+1] = temp;
            mushroom[j+1] = tempMush;
            cooking[j+1] = tempCook;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++){
    System.out.print(mushroom[i] + "\t\t" + weight[i] + "\t\t" + cooking[i] + "\n");
}
```

When I print the values of the arrays inside of the for loop, the values are correct, however outside of the while loop the code is printed as null, null and 0. However, the last three values are printed but I am sure that is something to do with my problem.

Anyway, I believe it is to do with scope.

After some searching, I discovered that java is "Pass by Value" instead of "Pass by Reference". I do not really understand this principal, but to my understanding it affects methods in particular, but all of my code is under a single method -- main. I tried to use return inside the for loop and outside but it does not work either!

Comment: Please remove the *"and then:"* and post the actual relation between the two code snippets.

Comment: @luk2302 got it

Comment: Okay, now please show how you are determining the values are null outside of the loop.

Comment: @Samuelf80 show us how you're printing outside the while loop

Comment: Its weird that the question is posted in multiple iterations , why not give all the required info at once

Comment: When I use System.out.println() for the values it prints them as just null when outside of the for loop, under all circumstances

Comment: @AmitKumar I didn't want you guys to think I just had a "aaaa not working... copy paste to stackoverflow...." attitude

Comment: The error is probably inside the first for loop as you're not adding values to the Arrays in an homogeneous way. Note that you're never adding any value to weight[0] as the only occasion where weight[i] receives a value is when i=1.

Comment: @Samuelf80  What you're saying could happen only when length of weight is 0/1 and the first values of all three arrays are uninitialized. See what values you have the  0th index of all three arrays inside the while loop. That could give you some clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are initially reading the values in seems quite off: you are placing the corresponding `weight` and `cooking` into different indices than the actual `mushroom` and you are using the index `i` in completely the wrong way. It should probably be

```
int i = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

    String[] temp = line.split(",");
    if(temp.length == 3)
        mushroom[i] = temp[0];
        weight[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);  
        cooking[i] = temp[2];
    } else {
        // some error handling
    }         
    i++;
 }
```

*"When I print the values of the arrays inside of the for loop, the values are correct"* is wrong - if you inspect `temp` the values are correct but `mushroom`, `weight` and `cooking` are never being filled correctly with your code.

Further note:

- try using a custom class to hold the associated values instead of dealing with 3 arrays which *magically* have something to do with each other. Then sort an array of instances of that class

Comment: However, I thought that i would be reset each time the for loop is exited - so the three values extracted from the line could be sent to their corresponding arrays, then get ready for the next line. I ammended my code with your code, however now it still prints out all of the errors - with purely nulls and 0s, as before on set of values were produced but now they are null again

Comment: @Samuelf80 there is not much I can do without a fully working example. All I *could* do would be to run the code again, and debug it - have *you* tried that already? Set a breakpoint in the `while` loop and inspect the three arrays at each iteration to see what *actually* happens in there

Comment: @Samuelf80 can you post your code on ideone.com, and share the link , it will be easier to find the problem

Comment: @Samuelf80 one last thing might be that the `null` values are being sorted in the first places causing you to see a lot of nulls before the actual values in the array. AND if your file contains more than 10 lines of mushrooms your code will crash.

Comment: FIxed! I forgot to change the output like an absolute mong. Thank you!!!!! My printing loop had changed to q instead of i, but the print was still mushroom[i] .. Then I spotted it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing/over-writing only first three elements in each mushroom, cooking and weight.
As

```
    i < temp.length,   i <= 3
```